# How to set up a 2D Array

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I am having some problems setting up a 2d array in ColdFusion. I set my array using:

```
<cfset lang=ArrayNew(2)>
<csset lang["ch"]["dealer1"] = "代理 1">
<csset lang["en"]["dealer1"] = "Dealer 1">
.....
```

But when I dump the array, it is empty. Can anyone help? I don't want to use number to set my language.

Comment: Among other problems, your code here shows `<csset `, which is not a valid CF tag.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike PHP - from which I suspect you are coming - there is the appropriate difference between an array (ordered and indexed numerically) and a struct (indexed by an arbitrary key value).

So you want something like:

```
myStruct = {akey="some value", subStruct={someKey="another value"}}; //etc
```

Comment: Well what did you do by way of trying to understand? Did you try the code & look at what it does? Did you look at the docs for structs?

Comment: As i understand for the code, ["ch"] = row of the table while ["dealer1"] is column of the table. But i dun want to put number and replace with these variables.

Comment: As Adam explained, arrays can only be indexed by numbers. If you want to index by a string, you need to use structs.

Comment: @chyman-91 there's no rows and columns: you're making it sound like a DB table. It's a struct. Have you read the docs on structs? I strongly suspect you have not. Because that's what you need to do next: not saying "I don't understand". If you don't understand, it's *your* job to make yourself understand; not ours.

Answer (score 3):

A ColdFusion `struct` is a string-based collection of data. There are plenty of [functions related to structs](http://cfdocs.org/struct-functions) that you'll need to learn.

Start off with the root struct that will contain your collection of data:

`<cfset lang = structNew() />`

Underneath that, you want two more collections of data. Each collection has its own root, which in your case is a language code.

```
<cfset lang.ch = structNew() />
<cfset lang.en = structNew() />
```

Now you can being adding `keys` to each sub-struct:

```
<cfset lang["ch"]["dealer1"] = "代理 1">
<cfset lang["en"]["dealer1"] = "Dealer 1">
```

Alternately,

```
<cfset lang.ch.dealer1 = "代理 1">
<cfset lang.en.dealer1 = "Dealer 1">
```

Now dump out the contents of the struct `lang`, and set the page encoding to UTF-8, to visualize how ColdFusion stores the data.

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="utf-8" />

<cfset lang = structNew() />
<cfset lang.ch = structNew() />
<cfset lang.en = structNew() />

<cfset lang["ch"]["dealer1"] = "代理 1">
<cfset lang["en"]["dealer1"] = "Dealer 1">

<cfdump var="#lang#" />
```

[image: A CFDUMP of struct contents.]

This should start you on your way. Dig into those functions and the [ColdFusion documentation on structs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-arrays-and-structures/structure-examples.html) before you go any further.

Comment: Why O *why* are you teaching people CFML coding styles from a decade ago? `structNew()`? Using tags for logic? I mean good on you for taking a less "socratic method" approach to mine, but at least demonstrate current-era code-quality in your code samples :-|

Comment: Gotta walk before you can run.

Comment: Ok thakz, now i understand it

Comment: Another question may not related with this question, can i for loop the struct using from and to in a function?

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno I think it's disingenuous to suggest learning assignment statements in tags is in any way easier than script. It's the opposite if anything, as it doesn't rely quite so much on how idiosyncratic tags-based CFML code is compared to other languages. That's even before getting to whether writing logic in tags ought to be encouraged at all.